# Python next () function

Tags: python

I'm writing program to find unique digits in a number and got this solution but I want to know how this works?

```
print(next(len(set(list(x))) if 1<=int(x)<=25000 else "Number should be >=1 and <=25000" for x in [input()]))
```

Comment: Well it's doing a lot of things. Which part are you unsure about?

Comment: This code doesn't "find unique numbers in a digit", and the problem is the `next()` call

Comment: @alec_djinn This code actually finds the number of unique digits in a number. Also the `next` function is working. What's wrong with this? Don't close the question, it's perfectly clear

Comment: @alec_djinn: The program is abusing a generator expression as a way to bind the `input()` return value to a variable. The generator expression produces a single value, and the `next` extracts that value. (This really should have been written across multiple statements instead of forcing everything into one line.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Exactly! It's basically the same thing as `print([len(set(list(x))) if 1<=int(x)<=25000 else "Number should be >=1 and <=25000" for x in [input()]][0])`

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite the solution in another way and comment it:

```
# Read the number (as a string, for example '3455')
x = input()
# Convert the string to an int ('3455' --> 3455) and check if the condition holds
if 1 <= int(x) <= 25000:
    # Create a list of digits ('3455' --> ['3', '4', '5', '5'])
    lst = list(x)
    # Find unique digits (['3', '4', '5', '5'] --> {'3', '4', '5'})
    s = set(lst)
    # Count the number of unique digits
    c = len(s)
    # Print the result
    print(c)
else:
    # If the condition 1 <= x <= 25000 does not hold then print an error message
    print("Number should be >=1 and <=25000")
```

You one line solution does exactly the same thing. I would say that it's not very "clear", still it works (as long as you input a number, and not something else, such as "3455g").

Comment: People who downvote: please tell me what I did wrong and how I can improve this solution. In casse I can also delete it if you don't like it. Just please motivate your downvote

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "find unique digits in a number" meaning that you want to see which digits are unique then you can use this code:

```
x = input()
print((list(set(x))) if 1<=int(x)<=25000 else "Number should be >=1 and <=25000")
```